# vowpal wabbit throwing incompatible version error

Tags: vowpalwabbit

I have a model file model.vw 
I am running the command
 
`vw -i model.vw  -t --daemon --quiet --port 26542` 
whenever I try to run this in daemon mode I get the error of incompatible version while the latest release is 8.2.0
How can I fix this ? The error is

> vw (vw_validate.cc:14): Model has possibly incompatible version! 8.3.2

Comment: The newest released tag is [8.3.1](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/tags) and GitHub head contains version [8.3.2](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/master/configure.ac#L1). Perhaps the model was created with the GitHub head version. You can update to this version as well or downgrade the vw which created the model. Are you sure it is an error, or just a warning?

Answer (score 0):

turns out if you build from the source code it gives a version above the current released version, fixed the issue by moving to the latest stable release which was 8.2.0